# Repository Disabled

Tags: github, repository, organization

I have been a member of a certain organization on Github. For the past year, I was able to access all the private repositories tagged to my account, until today. When I open the private repos, I was given this message:

**Repository Disabled**

This repository is currently disabled. 
Please contact an owner of the  organization to resolve the issue.

I googled and I got no answer about this.

Can anybody please help me out if what went wrong? Could this mean that someone with administrative access removed my account from getting access to all our private repos? Nonetheless, it's unlikely because I can still view the list of private repos on my account. I just can't open any of it.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks ahead! :)

Comment: Do all your private repos belong to organization? Can you pull or push?

Comment: Yes, Andrea. I've been accessing it for quite a while. That's why I was surprised when this happened earlier today.

Comment: Maybe you were moved from a group to another with less permissions..

Or, if you can push and pull normally, is only an internal GitHub error.

Comment: Hmm...my other colleagues also had the same issue. I'm still investigating this. I'll let you know when I already have an answer.

Comment: I don't think your repo administrator is revoking access to everyone :D Maybe it was only an internal error..

Comment: Hmm...it's ok now. They said, the CC number was changed. LOL. Anyway, thanks for your response @Andrea. :)

Answer (score 30):

If it is an organization with private repos, that means they are paying for a monthly plan.

If they stop paying, access to those private repos will be disabled.

As soon as they continue to pay, access would be restored and everything will go back to normal.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can i pay the payment as a member but not as an admin?

Comment: you need to be either an Admin or a Billing Manager https://github.com/organizations/REPO_NAME/billing_managers/new